# Calculating Kwh used from electric readings mysql

Tags: mysql, database, data-binding

```
consumer_id reading_date  previous           present         KWH used

10            January       0                 30                   30
10            February     30                 60                   30
10            March        60                 70                   10
12            January       0                 30                   30
12            February     30                 30                   15
```

Consumption Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `consumption` (
`consumption_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `reading_date` date NOT NULL,
  `readings` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `kwh_used` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `meter_reader_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `consumer_id` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `consumption` (`consumption_id`, `reading_date`, `readings`, `kwh_used`, `meter_reader_id`, `consumer_id`) VALUES
(14, '2013-07-30', 14386, 0, 1, 10),
(20, '2013-08-03', 14390, 0, 1, 10),
(29, '2013-07-30', 144, 0, 1, 12),
(31, '2013-07-31', 144, 0, 1, 12),
(34, '2013-08-03', 144, 0, 1, 12);
```

please check my queries below on how to get the output the same as the 1st table posted above.

```
SET @curRank1 = 0;
SET @curRank2 = 0;
SELECT
    D1.reading_date
    ,D1.consumer_id
    ,D1.readings AS previous
    ,D2.readings AS present
    ,(D2.readings - D1.readings) AS kwh_used
FROM 
( 
    SELECT M1.*, @curRank1 := @curRank1 + 1 AS rank
    FROM consumption M1
    LEFT JOIN consumption M2
    ON Date(M1.reading_date) = Date(M2.reading_date)
    AND M1.reading_date > M2.reading_date
    WHERE M2.reading_date IS NULL
) D2
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT M1.*, @curRank2 := @curRank2 + 1 AS rank
    FROM consumption M1
    LEFT JOIN consumption M2
    ON Date(M1.reading_date) = Date(M2.reading_date)
) D1
ON D2.rank = (D1.rank + 1)  
WHERE D1.reading_date IS NOT NULL
```

the output of that query is like this

```
reading_date    consumer_id     previous    present    kwh_used     
2013-07-30       10             14386       14390       4
2013-07-30       12             144         144         0
2013-08-03       10             14390       144         -14246
2013-08-03       12             144         144         0
```

as you can see the queries returns the series of readings which is bad because readings have different consumer_id. Please let me know what I'm missing here.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see how the desired result set relates to the data set !?!

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
and M1.consumer_id = m2.consumer_id
```

to each of your subqueries, and similarly to the `join` between them.

I think there are simpler ways to get what you want (correlated subuqeries or using variables).  But if you want to fix your query, put `consumer_id` in the join conditions.